B1 b2 visa query
I have travelled twice on a b2 visa to the USA. I was told on renewal it would be an interview waiver and drop box without a bank statement. I work in a family owned business. I sometimes get a salary paychek from my father's personal account otherwise its mostly company account. Is it okay to deposit cheque from his personal account to my savings account? I can provide a payslip on the company letterhead.the amount in my payslip will match the bank statement. I have to renew the b2 visa. If i have to show a bank statement will the above be an issue? The cheque series will be different for personal than a currw t account.

Why does your father sometimes pay you out of his personal account? Is the amount the same when he pays you as when the company pays you?

I’m not an accountant, nor am I familiar with US visa renewals, however I’m struggling to see how a company could issue a ‘payslip’ to you without having paid any money to you personally.

Yes the money is the same always as the company pays. Hes the proprietor there and its a small firm. Is it ok if i deposited cash this one month in jan ? Thats an option too

@Mohd Is the business a company (incorporated), or a sole trader? Normal practice is to keep business and personal accounts 100%  separate.. Depositing cash  might raise questions about its source. Keep it simple, have the business pay you direct.

Yes its a company incorporated.

@Mohd You need to get your terminology correct. If the business is incorporated, then it sounds like your father is the sole director and you are an employee with a contract of employment from the company. That doesn’t mean your father can legally pay you out of his personal account and have the company give you a payslip. That would, IMHO, be contrary to rules governing how a company must operate. Even if the business is a sole trader, it is standard accountancy practice to keep personal and business finances separate.

Well. I checked with a few travel agents here n its okay. I releber applying for a uk visa 2 yrs ago with the same cheques from personal account. Our bank statements only say chq deposit and nothing else

@Mohd Not necessarily a good indication since your UK visa was refused. If it’s that easy in your country to get what seems to be a false payslip, you can be pretty sure the local visa issuing office will know about the practice. They might ask to see the company’s bank statements.
